# Python: subclass calling parent methods only

Tags: python, overloading, subclassing

I have a rather strange situation in which I would like the class inheritance to work slightly different.

Consider this example:

```py
class A:
    def method1(self):
        print('A method 1')

    def method2(self):
        print('A method 2')
        self.method1()

class B(A):
    def method1(self):
        print('B method 1')

    def method2(self):
        print('B method 2')
        super().method2()
b = B()
b.method2()
```

Running this code will produce:

- B method 2
- A method 2
- B method 1

But what I would like to have is:

- B method2
- A method 2
- **A** method 1

To obtain this result, I have found this workaround:

```
class A:
    def method1(self):
        print('A method 1')

    def method2(self):
        print('A method 2')
        if isinstance(self, B):
            super(B, self).method1()
        else:
            self.method1()

class B(A):

    def method1(self):
        print('B method 1')

    def method2(self):
        print('B method 2')
        super().method2()

b = B()
b.method2()
```

But I'm afraid that breaking the normal hierarchical inheritance could have other unexpected drawbacks.

Do you know a better way?

Thanks for you help,

Comment: Why not use composition instead of inheritance to avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: I can't understand what *practical problem you hope to solve* by breaking the rules this way. The **point** of inheritance is that `method1` can choose the implementation according to the actual type of `self`, no matter the calling context. It also isn't clear: **What should happen** if **any other subclass** has `method2` called? What about the base class? **Why** does the base `method2` call the base `method1` in the first place, and **why** do derived classes override `method1`, if you don't want the override to be used?

Comment: If you want to ensure that `A.method2` always calls `A.method1`, then instead of `self.method1()` do `A.method1(self)`…

Comment: See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133817)

Comment: Thanks all for the fast answers. I knew that my solution was not the best, otherwise I would not have asked your opinion.

The reason why I wanted to use this solution is rather difficult to explain while maintaining a general level. All in all it means that my design was faulty since the beginning and requires a bit more of thinking. 

Thanks again